# Scala/Play Framework: Getting Payload from a POST request / NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala, dictionary, playframework, nosuchelementexception

I try to get the payload from a POST in Play 2.3.

Therefore I use this expression.

```
val name = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption)
```

But I run into trouble, when the field "name" is not present. Using the debugger, I can see that **request.body.asFormUrlEncoded** is of type Some(Map) or ListMap? I'm not sure, in the debugger both terms are displayed. When the field "name" exists, everything is fine, but if the field "name" is missing, it throws an NoSuchElementException.

I can see that only calling **request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("name")** does return an ArrayBuffer. But shouldn't it return a Some(ArrayBuffer) and a None in case of "name" field is not existing?

So what can I do to query the value of a field without generating an exception if the field is missing.

Added:
Here is the declaration of AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded. So it's a Map. But get on a Map should return Some or None, but not directly the object.

```
case class AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded(data: Map[String, Seq[String]]) extends AnyContent
```

Comment: Why can't you just set up a handler for that exception? It's pretty good thing to know if the field actually exists and make your program to handle that situation if it doesn't.

Comment: That's not the thing. Of course I could put it in a try catch block. But aren't exceptions only the second best solution. - I played around in the REPL and if I have a Map there and call get("xxx") on it and there is no xxx in the map, it returns a None. Otherwise I get a Some(anything). So the question is, why does "get" on the Map of FormUrlEncoded not return an Option? In the scala documentation of "get" on Map or ListMap it says that "get" returns an Option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered a Scala limitation here:

The call to the .get function is done on your `Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]`, then you use `("name")` which is translated into `.apply("name")`. You are actually calling the `apply` of the `Map` object which can throw an exception if the key is not in your map.

To avoid this you can use:

```scala
val name: Option[String] = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.flatMap(m => m.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption))
```

Comment: Using double get   get.get("name")   does the same. This is realy tricky if you new to scala. The double flatMap is more stable I think, but in my case the first get can't fail. What is the more performant way. Using get.get or using flatMap(get)?

Comment: I think it's better to be safe from start, so I would go for the flatMap except if you want your application to throw an exception if your body is not UrlEncoded